# PL/SQL - How to use an array in an IN Clause

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to use an array of input values to my procedure in an IN Clause as part of the where clause of a cursor.  I know that this has been asked before, but I haven't seen how to make my syntax compile correctly.

In the package specification, the type is

```
TYPE t_brth_dt IS TABLE OF sourceTable.stdt_brth_dt%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
```

`sourceTable.std_brth_dt` is a date column in the table.

Simplified version of my cursor is in the package body is -

```
 cursor DataCursor_Sort( p_brth_dt in t_brth_dt) is
    SELECT *
      FROM sourceTable 
     WHERE a.brth_dt IN (select column_value 
                           from table(p_brth_dt))
```

When I try to compile this, I'm getting  the following errors.

> - [1]:(Error): PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
> - [2]:(Error): PL/SQL: ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item

I know this looks similar to other questions, but I don't understand what the syntax error is.

Comment: try p_brth_dt in (select sourceTable.std_brth_dt from t_brth_dt)

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing an array into oracle sql and using the array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069458/passing-an-array-into-oracle-sql-and-using-the-array)

Comment: It is pathetic that an (apparently) enterprise-grade Procedural Language cannot deal with the simple concepts of arrays.

Comment: Using pipelined functions as suggested by Clever Idea Widgetry works well. The only thing I had to add was some code to ignore exception no_data_needed, as my program was throwing error ORA-06548. exception when no_data_needed then null;

Answer (score 4):

In order to use collection defined as a nested table or an associative array in the `from` clause of a query you either should, as @Alex Poole correctly pointed out, create a schema level (SQL) type or use one, that is available to you trough `ODCIConst` package - `odcidatelist` as you intend to use a list of dates. For example, your cursor definition might look like this:

```
cursor DataCursor_Sort(p_brth_dt in sys.odcidatelist) is
  select *
    from sourceTable 
   where a.brth_dt IN (select column_value 
                         from table(p_brth_dt))
```

OR

```
cursor DataCursor_Sort(p_brth_dt in sys.odcidatelist) is
  select s.*
    from sourceTable      s
    join table(p_brth_dt) t
      on (s.brth_dt = t.column_value)
```

Note: You should take into consideration the time part of a date when performing a date comparison. If you want to compare date part only it probably would be useful to get rid of time part by using `trunc()` function.

Comment: In second statement typo - t.brth_dt = s.column_value should be s.brth_dt = t.column_value.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use a PL/SQL-defined nested table type (as opposed to a SQL-defined nested table type) ***indirectly*** in an `IN` clause of a `SELECT` statement in a PL/SQL package. You must use a `PIPELINED` function as an intermediary. It felt kind of clever to write, but I don't believe in its fundamental usefulness.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE so18989249 IS

   TYPE date_plsql_nested_table_type IS TABLE OF DATE;
   dates date_plsql_nested_table_type;

   FUNCTION dates_pipelined RETURN date_plsql_nested_table_type PIPELINED;

   PROCEDURE use_plsql_nested_table_type;

END so18989249;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY so18989249 IS

   FUNCTION dates_pipelined RETURN date_plsql_nested_table_type
      PIPELINED IS
   BEGIN
      IF (dates.count > 0)
      THEN
         FOR i IN dates.first .. dates.last
         LOOP
            IF (dates.exists(i))
            THEN
               PIPE ROW(dates(i));
            END IF;
         END LOOP;
      END IF;
   END;

   PROCEDURE use_plsql_nested_table_type IS
   BEGIN
      dates := NEW date_plsql_nested_table_type();

      -- tweak these values as you see fit to produce the dbms_output results you want
      dates.extend(5);
      dates(1) := DATE '2013-12-25';
      dates(2) := DATE '2013-01-01';
      dates(3) := DATE '2013-07-01';
      dates(4) := DATE '2013-09-03';
      dates(5) := DATE '2008-11-18';

      FOR i IN (SELECT o.owner,
                       o.object_name,
                       o.object_type,
                       to_char(o.last_ddl_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS last_ddl
                  FROM all_objects o
                 WHERE trunc(o.last_ddl_time) IN 
                       (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(dates_pipelined)) 
                       --uses pipeline function which uses pl/sql-defined nested table
      )
      LOOP
         dbms_output.put_line('"' || i.owner || '"."' || i.object_name || '" ("' || i.object_type || ') on ' || i.last_ddl);
      END LOOP;

   END;

END so18989249;
/

begin so18989249.use_plsql_nested_table_type; end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

The type has to be created at SQL level, not in a package. An SQL query doesn't know how to use any types defined in PL/SQL. So you'd have to do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_brth_dt IS TABLE OF date;
/
```

... and remove the type from your package specification. (Or give them different names, at least, and they won't be interchangeable in use). Because it's at SQL level, you also can't use `sourceTable.stdt_brth_dt%TYPE` in the declaration, unfortunately.